# Fake/mock .Net Core Dependency injection Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing

I am trying to create Integration test, but it also depends on a third party service I want to fake.
I have Console app .Net Core 3.1.

What I mean:

```
           var configuration = GetConfiguration();

            var serviceProvider = GetServiceProvider(configuration);

            var appService = serviceProvider.GetService<IConsumerManager>();

            appService.StartConsuming(commandLineArguments);
```

```
 private static IConfiguration GetConfiguration()
            => new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile(ConfigurationFile, true, true).Build(); 

private static ServiceProvider GetServiceProvider(IConfiguration config)
    {
        IServiceCollection collection = new ServiceCollection();

        collection.Configure<ConsumerConfig>(options => config.GetSection("consumerConfig").Bind(options));

        collection.AddSingleton<IConsumerManager, ConsumerManager>();
        collection.AddTransient<ISelfFlushingQueue, SelfFlushingQueue>();
        collection.AddTransient<IConsumer, Consumer>();
        collection.AddTransient<IConverter, Converter>();

        collection.AddFactory<IConsumerWorker, ConsumerWorker>();

        return collection.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
```

In my case I want to fake calls to Consumer.
And I am wondering if there is other way to fake calls to it than just creating Fake class and adding it to DI.
For example:

```
collection.AddTransient<IConsumer, FakeConsumer>();
```

Maybe somehow I could use FakeItEasy, NUnit or any other lib to fake this ?

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/moq/moq
Just create mock of your consumer like this: Mock.Of<IConsumer>() and register it as IConsumer. Quickstart: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create mocks using your favorite mocking framework and add them to your service collection.

Example using Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IConsumer>();
mock.Setup(foo => foo.DoSomething("ping")).Returns(true); // this line is just an example of mocking a method named DoSomething, you'll have to adapt it to the methods you want to mock

collection.AddTransient<IConsumer>(() => mock.Object);
```

https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: I'm attempting to do just this, but I'm getting a `CS1593: Delegate 'Func<IServiceProvider, IConsumer>' does not take 0 arguments` error.. Does it ring a bell?

Comment: Probably it is updated. and it is taking one input as param. use below code it should work

services.AddTransient<IYourServiceName>((_) => new Mock<IYourServiceName>().Object)

Comment: didnt work for me with AddTransient either. collection.AddSingleton(mock); worked tho.